# Console error when rendering Big React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I keep getting this console error message when rendering my BigCalendar component.

How can I solve this?

> "Uncaught Error: NoopWrapper.render(): A valid React element (or null)
>   must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some
>   other invalid object.
>       at invariant (invariant.js?994a:42)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?8c6a:828)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?8c6a:359)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?8c6a:255)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?af94:43)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js?0c7d:234)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js?9b5f:701)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js?9b5f:520)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?af94:43)
>       at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js?f170:119)"

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

const MyCalendar = () => {
    const dummyEvents = [
        {
            allDay: true,
            end: new Date('October 10, 2018 11:13:00'),
            start: new Date('October 09, 2018 11:13:00'),
            title: 'hi'
        }
    ];
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '60rem' }}>
            <BigCalendar
                events={dummyEvents}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                localizer={localizer}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyCalendar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be useful if you could specify which version of `react-big-calendar` you are using.

Anyway, I'm not sure what is causing the problem, but I also received this error when using version `0.20.1` of `react-big-calendar`. A temporary fix might be to downgrade and use for example version `0.19.2`.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, thomklei. I was using 0.20.1, but downgrading to 0.19.2 seemed to solve the problem.